# Установка OGRE 3D

Tags: c++, graphics

Добрый день. Помогите установить графический движок OGRE под Visual Studio 2017 или (в идеале) под CLion 2017. Windows 10. Хотелось бы получить подробную инструкцию, ибо перечитал много всего, но ничего так и не вышло.

Comment: Инструкции должны быть в документации к движку. Если их там нет или они устарели, стоит обратиться к тем, кто занимается их поддержкой. А Stack Overflow нужен уже для вопросов о конкретных трудностях.

Comment: @D-side У ТС конкретная трудность, он не может установить движок

Comment: @Cerbo "не может установить движок" потому что... (вставить конкретику сюда). Если он просто не может этого сделать, то вопрос оффтопик, т. к. это уже что-то из области психологии, нежели программирования.